# How to measure the total time in the system in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I would like to know how to measure the total time one agent expend in the system in discrete events simulation.
Can I use this code? Time=time()  timeDS.add(time()-Time); but allocating the *agent.Time+time()* in the exit in the source and *timeDs.add(time() agent.Time);* at on enter in the sink?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes you can.

You can also use the "On startup" and "on destroy" code fields of the agent properties, this is the true life span of your agent.

[image]

(And next time, maybe try it first ;) )